# Conditional Image Resizing with Photoshop and JavaScript according to original image heights

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am struggling to create a js code for Photoshop action. I have a file folder of different size images. Also these are different heights and widths. My script needs to:

**For each image:** 
Read the height and width. For whichever size is largest (height or width), create a white background square in Photoshop and place the image in the square. Save as 300 dpi jpg named filename_01. 
Do the same with the next image.

Example - if the first image is named angel.jpg and is 600 pixels in height and 400 pixels in width, photoshop would:
Create a white background .jpg blank image SQUARE that is 600x600 (since the height is the largest of the height/width dimensions). Place the image centered in the square. Save it as 300 dpi .jpg named angel_01.jpg.

If the next image is 520x390, the box would be 520 pixels. I found this JS code but it does not fulfil my requirement.

```js
// get a reference to the current (active) document and store it in a variable named "doc"
doc = app.activeDocument;  

// change the color mode to RGB.  Important for resizing GIFs with indexed colors, to get better results
doc.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);  

// these are our values for the end result width and height (in pixels) of our image
var fWidth = 500;
var fHeight = 500;

// do the resizing.  if height > width (portrait-mode) resize based on height.  otherwise, resize based on width
if (doc.height > doc.width) {
    doc.resizeImage(null,UnitValue(fHeight,"px"),null,ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
}
else {
    doc.resizeImage(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),null,null,ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
}

// call autoContrast and applySharpen on the active layer.
// if we just opened a gif, jpeg, or png, there's only one layer, so it must be the active one
doc.activeLayer.autoContrast();
doc.activeLayer.applySharpen();

// our web export options
var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
options.quality = 70;
options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
options.optimized = true;

var newName = 'web-'+doc.name+'.jpg';

doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,options);
```

Comment: What does the script do presently, and where are you getting stuck with modifying it?

Comment: I just require to change image size according to original image height, e.g if image height is 1200px and image resized to 1200x1200px

Comment: there is may be some miner change required i just require a script in Photoshop to change according to opened image height and than convert into  with original image's height if image height is 1200px than 1200x1200px

Comment: Yes, but you may need to know that _Stack Overflow_ is not a free script repair service. It's here to _help_ people with their programming problems, so would you give it a go first?

Comment: i did not understand what do you mean? you require me to pay you in order to repair my code?

Comment: No, I did not say or mean that. I am saying that readers generally will ask you to make your own attempt first. Have you done any JavaScript before?

Answer (score 0):

OK. exceptionally for you Mirza Abdul Rahman. (Please transfer $ 50,000 to my bank account in Zurich) :-)

```js
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits; 
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

if (documents.length >= 1){

var hres = 0;
var vres = 0;
var CubSize = 0;
var OldName = activeDocument.name.substring(0, activeDocument.name.indexOf('.'));
var CurrentFolder = activeDocument.path;
hres = activeDocument.width;
vres =  activeDocument.height;

activeDocument.selection.selectAll();

if (activeDocument.layers.length >1) {
 activeDocument.selection.copy(true);
}

else{
 if (activeDocument.layers.length =1) {
 activeDocument.selection.copy(false);
 }
}


activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES); // Close Original Image

if (vres > hres) 
 CubSize=vres;    
else 
 CubSize=hres;                 
      

var newDoc = documents.add(CubSize,CubSize,72, OldName + '-01', NewDocumentMode.RGB, DocumentFill.WHITE);

newDoc.paste();
newDoc.mergeVisibleLayers(); 

jpgFile = new File(CurrentFolder + "/" + OldName+"_01" + ".jpg" );
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 7;
newDoc.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true,   Extension.LOWERCASE);

}
```

Comment: thanks for code, and yes i definetly transfer 50000 but not us in Rs. but there is issue the script is change only canvas size not image if it is not possible than only change image not canvas size i will after change image create another action that change canvas

Comment: here is js code but i require to change only image size not canvas size    var savedRuler= app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var w = app.activeDocument.width;
var h = app.activeDocument.height;
if(w>h) app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas (w, w, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
if(w<h) app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas (h, h, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
//if w==h already square
app.preferences.rulerUnits = savedRuler;

Comment: hello Goldmoon, I just require js code to change image size according to original image height or width whatever is bigger height or width than square image to bigger size

Comment: Hello Mirza... the problem: If you are just working on the original image, it can have a transparant Background, a colorful Background, or itself is the Background. These are too many factors that you should consider in the script, and too many possible error sources.

My script copies the original image (checks whether it consists of one or more layers). creates a new image with the desired dimensions (as a white square), and inserts the original image. You only have to add the code to save the new Image(newDoc).

Comment: yeh you are right, i have checked image after script action the image size is not changing image size is same i require image size to be change with highest size whether height or width whatever is  bigger than re-size canvas as square

Comment: The new image has the desired dimensions (square, depending on the highest side-length of Original Image). The original image remains unchanged. You can activate the code to close the original image. (activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);).

Comment: I have edited the code, the new code is fully functional. (in short: Copy Original Image, Close it, Create new Image as you described, Save new Image)

Comment: you are genius Goldmoon... i really appreciate your contribution stay bless.

Comment: Thank you Mirza. I have overlooked the 300 dpi... Change for that the Value 72 to 300:     var newDoc = documents.add(CubSize,CubSize,300, OldName + '-01', NewDocumentMode.RGB, DocumentFill.WHITE);

Comment: The problem with assisting [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) is that you end up [encouraging them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35483930/472495).